# Zxing - Where I can find these files? zxing-all-in-one.cpp and zxing-all-in-one.h

Tags: c++, ios, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, zxing

I'm using worklight for my mobile app project. My problem is, I dont know where I can find these files (zxing-all-in-one.cpp and zxing-all-in-one.h) for barcode scanner integration with worklight in Xcode5. Since ChildBrowser plugin alreade deprecated, check this out. https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/BarcodeScanner

I read through this blog regarding to zxing integration with worklight.

http://sajjad-hussainsh.blogspot.com/2013/05/ibm-worklight-phonegap-barcodescanner.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/wildabeast/BarcodeScanner/tree/master/src/ios

This link will give you both the required files

Comment: so, when I apply .../master/src/ios into my project (i want to use this source code to build library.a file).
I have issue is in zxing-all-in-one.h, 'map' file not found??
I just added  libiconv.tdv to project.
Could you help me, why Xcode has error  is 'map' file not found

Comment: I also have this issue.